# Difference between binary string, byte string, unicode string and an ordinary string (str)

Tags: python

I'm a little confused. In Python what is the difference between a binary string, byte string, unicode string and a plain old string (str)? I'm using Python 2.6.

Comment: You should specify whether you are using Python 2 or Python 3 because it makes a huge difference.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?  And where did you encounter the term "binary string" in the context of Python?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm using Python 2.6. I wanted to convert a string to binary data and that's when I came across the term.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on the version on Python you are using.

In Python 2.x if you write `'abc'` it has type `str` but this means a byte string. If you want a Unicode string you must write `u'abc'`.

In Python 3.x if you write `'abc'` it still has type `str` but now this means that is a string of Unicode characters. If you want a byte string you must write `b'abc'`. It is not allowed to write `u'abc'`.

```
        |  2.x                     |  3.x
--------+--------------------------+-----------------------
Bytes   |  'abc' <type 'str'>      |  b'abc' <type 'bytes'>
Unicode | u'abc' <type 'unicode'>  |   'abc' <type 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Just so I understand properly, basically the difference between a byte string and an ordinary string is that a byte string can't contain unicode characters?

Comment: @Imran Azad: You can think of a byte string as an ordered list of bytes - that is integers between 0 and 255 inclusive. A Unicode string is an ordered list of Unicode characters (letters, numbers, punctuation, tiny snowmen (☃), etc). The confusion I think comes from Python 2.x treating byte strings as if they were strings of characters. That almost works, except when you start using characters outside of the ASCII range you run into problems.

Comment: `bytes` also exists in 2.x, but is a synonym for `str`.